# Android image animation - moving on a trajectory

Tags: android, translate-animation

I'd like to have an animated image in my activity:
just a white circle moving on a trajectory (black line).

[image]

What is the best way to do it?

1. Translate animation
2. FrameAnimation
3. Canvas

The implementation could be:

1. The white circle is a small ImageView with transparent background. It is placed on top of another ImageView (black curve).
2. FrameAnimation: For each position of the circle there is a separate png-Image of the whole screen, which is a frame of the animation.
3. Use drawCircle(), and restoreBackgroundImage() for each movement of the white dot.

So far I tried a FrameAnimation, but I get outOfMemoryError for just 10 Frames.

Comment: try https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids

Answer (score 0):

The following code implements the `Canvas` way. Efficient and no OOM. You just need to change your trajectory into a `Path` object.

```
public class TestView extends View {
    private Path path;
    private Paint pathPaint;
    private Paint dotPaint;
    private long beginTime;
    private long duration = 3000;
    private float dotRadius = 3;
    private PathMeasure pm;

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, 100);
        path.lineTo(100, 200);
        path.lineTo(200, 50);
        //TODO: Put your path here

        pm = new PathMeasure(path, false);
        pathPaint = new Paint();
        pathPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        pathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        dotPaint = new Paint();
        dotPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        dotPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        beginTime = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float currentDistance;

        if (beginTime == 0) {
            beginTime = currentTime;
            currentDistance = 0;
        } else if (beginTime > 0 && currentTime - beginTime < duration) {
            currentDistance = (float) (currentTime - beginTime) / (float) duration * pm.getLength();
        } else {
            beginTime = -1;
            return;
        }

        float pos[] = new float[2];
        pm.getPosTan(currentDistance, pos, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(pos[0], pos[1], dotRadius, dotPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```